# how to sketch the field lines of $F(x,y)=(\sin y,-\sin x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-analysis, vector-fields

how to sketch the field lines of $\vec{F}(x,y)=(\sin y,-\sin x)$?

If i use the usual method,then i have $\frac{dx}{dt}=\sin y$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}=-\sin x$. To draw the field line, i have to solve
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\sin x}{\sin y}$$

But if i solve this ODE, i get
$\cos y=-\cos x +C \Rightarrow y=\cos^{-1}(-\cos x +C)$

Now, here comes the question, how do I draw the field line **without using computer?**

Or,**is there any other way** to sketch the field lines other than the method i used above?

Comment: I don't' know how to explain it. I will try: Consider the line $x=pi$. On this, $\vec F$ has only horizontal direction. In addition, the arrows forms a sine. Or better, the arrows are such that the envolvent is the sine graph (rotated 90 degrees of course). You can repeat that for the lines $x=n\pi$, $n$ integer and also for $y=n\pi$. For other values, I have to think about it more time.

Comment: My advice is you should focus on computing $\vec F(x,y)$ for $(x,y)=(2m\pi,2n\pi)$ and $(x,y)=((2m+1)\pi/2,2(n+1)\pi/2)$, with $m,n\in\mathbb Z$.  I think for a sketch it is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Which information other than the diagram below, are you after?

[image]

Comment: this is a diagram generated by Wolfram Alpha, what i'm asking is: is it possible to draw this diagram without using a computer?

Comment: The directions N, W, S, E, NW, SW, SE and NE of the vector field are trivial to establish. From there, one can guess the shape of the solutions.

Comment: Furthermore, each square translated of the square $|x|+|y|=\pi$ is invariant, its boundary too, and in each such square the direction field I mentioned is clear. Finally, the invariant function $H(x,y)=\cos x+\cos y$ shows the solutions inside the square are cycles. This is the complete picture.